# Speedy impeachment trial requirement

Tags: impeachment

How soon must the house send the impeachment charges to the senate?  Is there a time limit on how long they could be held in the house?  Do they "go away" if not forwarded in a certain time frame?

Comment: If you have a few minutes, there's a short, readable and balanced article on this question by Frank Bowman, an expert on impeachment, at The Atlantic. He gives principled and prudential reasons why the House should not delay sending the articles to the Senate: https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2019/12/house-dems-cannot-force-senate-fair-trial/603928/